# Kubuntu, app installed from Discover dont appear in KDE menu

Tags: kubuntu, kde

So basically the title, I'm using the latest version of Kubuntu, and the apps installed through discover marketplace dont appear on the menu.

Comment: Please be specific.  What is the *latest* release to you? and what *apps* specifically are you using?   Some packages viewable in package managers including `discover` do not show in menus, being back-ends, libraries, fonts etc. that are used from within other packages/apps you start.

Comment: Actually any software I install, chrome, vscode, dbeaver, just normal consumer software, no backend processes.